# Pretty print pandas: how to set the columns as displayed rows (and rows as displayed columns)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pretty-print

Any ideas on how to set the columns as displayed rows, and hence displaying the rows as columns in pandas?

Currently printing a dataframe outputs something like this:

```
      K      T  best_testing_rmse  best_training_rmse  chan_out_dim  \
48   15  20000  1.24502685         1.24942538          15             
217  15  20000  1.25521732         1.24871174          15             

     dropout_p g_hid g_in g_latent    g_rij  \
48   0.1        tanh  elu  linear   sigmoid   
217  0.1        tanh  elu  linear   sigmoid   

                           harvest_dir  hid_dim  input_dropout_p  \
48   ./harvest_autorec_20170103_175735  50       0.1               
217  ./harvest_autorec_20170103_175730   50       0.1               

     last_testing_rmse  last_training_rmse        lr  max_epoch  \
48   1.52006088         1.52138316          0.000002  1403        
217  1.31366942         1.30483602          0.000002  1056        

     minibatch_size  n_epochs  n_hid_layers optimizer preprocessing_type  \
48   1               20000     1             gpu_omp   zscore              
217  1               20000     1             gpu_omp   zscore              

    regression_error_coef regression_type  regularization_lambda  \
48   0.5                   item            0.001                   
217  0.5                   item            0.001                   

     regularization_latent_kl stochastic_prediction            upd  
48   0.5                       False                 adam_symbolic  
217  0.5                       False                 adam_symbolic
```

This is particularly inconvenient. Much better view this table rotated of 90 degrees.

Comment: Sorry are you asking how to transpose? e.g. `df.T`?

Comment: And if you want everything in one column you can use `df.stack()`

Comment: @EdChum : thank you, that's what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is to `transpose` which can be called using [`.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas.DataFrame.T) which rotates the df so that the columns becomes rows and vice versa:

```
In [31]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), index=list('vwxyz'), columns=list('abc'))
df

Out[31]:
          a         b         c
v  0.218951 -0.716086  0.620063
w -0.672559  0.311909  0.326861
x  0.866325 -0.591517 -0.387572
y -0.749873  1.645110 -1.185780
z -0.796720 -1.974399  0.546645

In [32]:
df.T

Out[32]:
          v         w         x         y         z
a  0.218951 -0.672559  0.866325 -0.749873 -0.796720
b -0.716086  0.311909 -0.591517  1.645110 -1.974399
c  0.620063  0.326861 -0.387572 -1.185780  0.546645
```